# Implementing JWT with Spring security using random username

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt

I'm currently planning to use JWT to secure my API, I have read several tutorials, and find that generally, it's using username and password to generate token, while the UserDetail is got and constructed from a database.

Now I have a question, if I cannot get the UserDetail for some reason, can I use some random data, like UUID replacing username, to identify each request?

---

**update:**

I feel if I just use the token to distinguish per request, actually it's not so called oauth2, it's just JWT token.

Actually previously our solution is,  we generate a token and store it in Redis before each request , then we verify if the token expires in Redis in each request.

As the customers don't need to login to purchase something, we don't have UserDetail info, Now I feel almost no difference between two solutions, and I'm even wondering if the JWT token alone gives better security.

^_^

Comment: User name is a `String`, you could convert you UUID to a `String` and use it as an user name.